# Kotlin How to use custom click listener with lambda instead of declaring object : CustomClass

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, onclick, onclicklistener

This is my interface:

```
interface DialogOkClickListener {
    fun onDialogOkClick()
}
```

This is my clickListener

```
fun setOkClickListener(okClickListener: DialogOkClickListener): DialogOkCancel {
    this.okClickListener = okClickListener
    return this
}
```

This is how it currently works:

```
 .setOkClickListener(object  : DialogOkCancel.DialogOkClickListener{
     override fun onDialogOkClick() {
         TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
     }
 })
```

But if I try something like:

```
 .setCancelClickListener{ methodToCall() }
```

I get `type missmatch found () -> String`

Comment: Just to confirm it should be `.setCancelClickListener{ "bla" }` of `.setOkClickListener{ "bla" }`?

Comment: my interface just has 1 method to call onDialogOkClick(). Which I need to override. So I want that to call a method/fun. I want to make the fun a lambda.
I edited my question, hope it's more understandable

Comment: i don't think you can, overrides always need to be with the syntax of `object  : DialogOkCancel.DialogOkClickListener` AFAIK

Comment: @rosualin please check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In java, there is `SAM conversion` which is an automatic conversion of a `lambda` into an interface with a `single abstract method`. It is not supported for interfaces defined in `Kotlin`. 
And therefore you have to define your implementation like this

```
    object  : DialogOkCancel.DialogOkClickListener{
     override fun onDialogOkClick() {
         TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
     }
    }
```

Check out this link https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770

It is preferable to use `functional types` (e.g. Click -> Unit) instead of `functional interfaces` if possible.

What you can do is this

```
interface DialogOkClickListener {
    fun onDialogOkClick()
}

private val clickEvent = {}

fun DialogOkCancel.setOkClickListener(
        click: () -> Unit = clickEvent
): DialogOkClickListener {
    return object : DialogOkClickListener {
        override fun onDialogOkClick() {
            click()
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
DialogOkCancel.setOkClickListener{ /*Do anything*/ }
```

> Note: Here I have created `kotlin extension function`